Parse platform on Expo--can't access objects
Trying to learn React Native / Expo.
Have an existing Parse server, need to connect to it.
Seem to be able to initialize but not access objects.
Example code:
export const initializeParseClient = () => {
  // Initialize client; this works
  Parse.initialize("...", "...");
  Parse.serverURL = "...";  

  // try accessing an object and examining a field; doesn't work
  const query = new    Parse.Query("DoctorInfo");
  try {
      //set query to get the object with the given ID
      query.equalTo("objectId", docId);
      //execute the query and return the result
      const doctorInfo = await query.first();
      const practice = doctorInfo.get("Practice");
      console.log(`Practice: ${practice}`);
      return practice; 
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching DoctorInfo:', error);
      throw error;
  }
};

When I run this from the MacOS Terminal in Expo Go, I get this error:
Error fetching DoctorInfo: [Error: unauthorized]

...any help?
